# Spring aop aspect: using ".." not working to replace parameters?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop, spring-web

I have the following pointcut defined, which works great.

```
@Pointcut("args(req, resp) && (execution(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller+.*(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)))")
```

However, if I change it to the following pointcut, removing the response variable and replacing it with `..`:

```
@Pointcut("args(req) && (execution(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller+.*(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, ..)))")
```

The pointcut does not have any markers and never gets executed, strangely.

Any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the first part of your composed pointcut i.e args(req). It matches a method which takes a single argument.

The second part i.e 
`execution(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller+.*(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, ..))`

matches a method which has at least one argument of type HttpServletRequest.

However Controller interface method handleRequest takes two arguments.

Change this part `args(req)` of the pointcut to `args(req,..)`

```
@Pointcut("args(req,..) && (execution(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller+.*(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, ..)))")
```